# Animated ContourPlot Color Rescaling

Tags: plotting, animation, visualization, generative-art, rendering

My goal is to create a smooth animation of a changing ContourPlot. Unfortunately, the colors specified in ContourShading seem to bounce around during the animation. Below is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
contoureq[x_, y_, z_] := 
 Evaluate[Sum[Cos[RandomReal[5, 3] . {x, y, z}], {5}]]
VideoGenerator[
 Table[ContourPlot[contoureq[x, y, z], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
   ContourShading -> {Cyan, Green, Blue, Purple}, Frame -> False], {z, 0, Pi, Pi/15}], 
 CompressionLevel -> 0, FrameRate -> 60]
```

Using this approach, I created a video which can be seen below (colors different from above example).

[image: output of video generator]

In the video, the animation doesn't look smooth because the colors used are jumping around as the image rescales. How can I prevent this erratic color switching from happening? I tried adding `PlotRange -> All` as an argument of `ContourPlot` but I wasn't able to resolve the issue. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You can also set the values of the contours themselves.  Check the documentation.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you, I think that fixed the issue.